# How to bind custom nib view to Siesta ResourceStatusOverlay public outlets

Tags: ios, siesta-swift

I've created a custom view in Interface Builder and set the File's Owner to ResourceStatusOverlay.
I would like to bind subviews from the .xib to ResourceStatusOverlay @IBOutlet. I've tried dragging the connections from .xib to ResourceStatusOverlay.swift connectors and vice versa with no luck.

Any help in doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: There’s a known issue with using ResourceStatusOverlay in nibs, apparently an Apple bug. See https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta/issues/4 and https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta/pull/85.

Comment: Thanks @PaulCantrell. I'll keep an eye on that.